# A riemann sum of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

An integral can be seen as a limiting case of a sum:
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f(k/n)}{n}.$$
What if we go one step further in this direction and consider
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{n-1}\frac{f(x/n)}{n}dx.$$
Is that a kind of "hyper-integral"? Can we compute this limit in general?

Comment: $u=x/n, du = (1/n) dx = \int_0^1 f(u) du$

Comment: With $u = x/n$ you have $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{1 - 1/n} f(u) du = \int_0^1f(x) dx.$ assuming $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$ then it must be bounded and

$$\left|\int_{1-1/n}^1 f(x) \, dx\right| \leqslant \int_{1-1/n}^1 |f(x)| \, dx \leqslant \frac{M}{n}.$$

Hence,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{n}\int_{0}^{n-1} f(x/n) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1-1/n} f(x) \, dx \\ =  \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx - \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{1-1/n}^{1} f(x) \, dx \\ = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx.$$

More generally, if $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[0,b]$ for all $0 < b < 1$ -- but not over $[0,1]$ -- then this limit is just the improper integral if it exists.